# How do I render the dots completely while keeping all the grid lines?

Tags: python, matplotlib

I'm trying to reproduce the figure from page 405 of "Thomas H. Cormen, Charles E. Leiserson, Ronald L. Rivest and Clifford Stein. Introduction to Algorithms, 3rd Edition. The MIT Press, 2009"

[image]

Here is the code

```
plt.plot(0,6,'o',c='k')
plt.plot(1,0,'o',c='k')
plt.plot((0,1),(6,0))
plt.xlim([0, 9])
plt.ylim([0, 7])
plt.grid()
```

which renders the dots incompletely

[image]

In contrast, the following code renders the dots completely though, the grid lines at x=1, 3, disappears

[image]

How do I render the dots completely while keeping all the grid lines?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using [`MultipleLocator`](https://matplotlib.org/stable/api/ticker_api.html#matplotlib.ticker.MultipleLocator). Also, it would be better to use the [object-oriented interface](https://matplotlib.org/matplotblog/posts/pyplot-vs-object-oriented-interface/) (`fig, ax = plt.subplots()`, `ax.plot()`), instead of the pyplot interface (`plt.plot()`).

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib.ticker import MultipleLocator

fig, ax = plt.subplots()
ax.plot(0,6,'o',c='k')
ax.plot(1,0,'o',c='k')
ax.plot((0,1),(6,0))
ax.set_xlim([-1, 9])
ax.set_ylim([-1, 7])
ax.yaxis.set_major_locator(MultipleLocator(1))
ax.xaxis.set_major_locator(MultipleLocator(1))
ax.grid()
```

Output:

[image]

The entire figure:

```
fig, ax = plt.subplots()
x = [0, 1, 6, 8, 7, 5, 2]
y = [6, 0, 1, 2, 5, 4, 3]
ax.fill(x, y, fill=False)
ax.scatter(x, y, c='k')
ax.set_xlim([-1, 9])
ax.set_ylim([-1, 7])
ax.yaxis.set_major_locator(MultipleLocator(1))
ax.xaxis.set_major_locator(MultipleLocator(1))
ax.grid()
ax.set_axisbelow(True)
```

[image]

EDIT:
Based on your (since-deleted) [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73988405/how-do-i-make-the-height-and-width-of-each-grid-cell-equal), use

```
ax.set_aspect('equal')
```

[image]